# Format HTML document

Tags: html, editor, notepad++, code-formatting

I like the feature in Visual Studio for formatting an HTML document (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

Is there a plugin with the same functionality in any other (free) editors, e.g. Notepad++?

Comment: Are you kidding me, this is a great question.  And it answered my problem.  Please reopen!

Comment: @irperez Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information.

Comment: Both these comments are true!  What a contradiction for SO... The best place for `our` questions.... is not the place for *all* of them. (Hence all the sister sites from here now, lol)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you mean colorizing and formatting from "Format", Notpad++ has HTML tidying feature via Tidy2 plugin. Install the plugin with the Plugin Manager, and a new menu Tidy2 item will appears under the Plugins, and from there you can formatting HTML.

Also Netbeans IDE has formatting(ALT+F) feature for many languages (including PHP, HTML, CSS and JS).

Comment: I mean, when I have not so viewable code (no tabs, no space etc...), I don't want to spend time to understand that one, I want to format in normal viewable code .

Comment: Use Tidy options in Notepad++, it has different formatting options.

Comment: TextFX > TextFX HTML Tidy > Tidy Note: Subject to change. Not sure why this answer wasn't accepted.

Comment: FYI TextFX in Notepad++ is a top level menu which is created after you install the TextFx plugin.

Comment: So, to be clear, this TextFX stuff is not "builtin" after all?

Comment: TextFX comes with the default Notepad++ install. It regrettably contains no formatting (as in: changing indentation into a structured thing)

Comment: If you don't see the menu, [follow these directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699833/textfx-menu-is-missing-in-notepad).

Comment: HTML tidy didn't come with TextFX for me follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985637/notepad-htmltidy-unable-to-find-libtidy-dll