# How can I make each tag (of any language) move to the next line?

Tags: tags, notepad++

in Notepad++ is there a way to make each tag (of any language) move to the next line?

instead of having tags stacked horizontaly like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h2>Norwegian Mountain Trip</h2><img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228"></body></html>
```

I would like to have each tag on a seperate line like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Norwegian Mountain Trip</h2>
<img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">

</body>
</html>
```

and I am not asking about word-wrap since it will not make each tag go on a seperate line.

is there a way to do that on Notepad++?

Thanks a lot!

Roy.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/auto-format-indent-for-xml-html-in-notepad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Search mode Extended selected, try find and Replace

Find `>`

Replace `>\n`

This will add a line feed after every tag ending with `>`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answers, both helped.