# How do I stop Tidy2 from adding additional HTML tags? (Notepad++)

Tags: php, html, formatting, notepad++

I'm attempting to use the Tidy2 plugin within Notepad++ to auto-format some HTML for prettiness. However, Tidy2 keeps adding HTML tags to my code, which would break the site functionality since I'm using PHP includes. Anyway, this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="RC_Contract">Contract</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="RC_Contract" name="RC_Contract" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">2 Year</option>
      <option value="2">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

turns into this after using Tidy2:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="RC_Contract">Contract</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select id="RC_Contract" name="RC_Contract" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">2 Year</option>
                    <option value="2">None</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use Tidy2 when your code is *UNTIDY*. Your primary code didn't have any code style problem. I really suggest you to use some tools like [HTMLPAD](http://www.htmlpad.net) for keeping your code style pretty from the beginning of coding. In case you use nice editors with good *autocomplete* you won't need any tools to make it tidy!

Comment: I'm really only using the Tidy2 feature to fix auto-indent issues. You're right, my code isn't Untidy - as in, everything is on the correct line. But it is spaced incorrectly from the left of the screen. There are a number of tabs(spaces) from the left of the file which you cannot see in my copy-pasted code on this site. Is it possible to auto-indent HTML, Javascript, and PHP with Notepad++?

Comment: as I said before the best solution is to write you code in a nice and easy-to-config IDE like PHPstorm. these IDEs have some configuration to have auto-indent during your coding. and you can config it as the way you like.

Answer (score 2):

This unwanted advertising makes Tidy2 a piece of crap.
For all those who are still stranding at this question: Try out "XML Tools" and it's pretty print option.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786249/2306536

Comment: I agree it's very annoying and kind of defeats the purpose of a quick html prettifier, since you then have to go and delete tags and unindent 2 layers.

Comment: Currently I am simply using Eclipse to edit .xml files, I have it open all day long anyways.