# How to indent HTML tags in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I installed Notepad++. How to make tags automatically indent especially when nesting? All the tags seem to be lining up to the left of the screen.

Comment: See [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad)

Comment: Yes. But mine gives an error it says: error detected in content please correct them before applying.

Comment: that normally means your xml code isn't valid. For instance the header is missing, or some tag isn't closed properly. In that case you shouldn't format (the original file). Since it can damage the content.

Comment: <!doctype> 
<html>
<head>
<title> Name of the site </title>
</head>
<body> 
<h1> Logo</h1>
</body>
</html>
</!doctype>

Comment: (1) that's HTML (there is a difference), (2) every xml file needs to start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>` (3) one doesn't need to close the doctype and you better omit it for xml processing, (4) one better uses tidy to convert to xml.

Comment: Any idea how to indent html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Auto-Format / Indent XML/HTML in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao “Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**.” This is **not** off-topic.

Answer (score 87):

Use the [XML Tools](http://www.herongyang.com/XML/NPP-XML-Tools-Plugin.html) plugin for Notepad++ and then you can Auto-Indent the code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> .For the more point-and-click inclined, you could also go to Plugins --> XML Tools --> Pretty Print.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+B didn't work, it inserted some random text, and Pretty Print, literally did nothing (with an actual XML file even) -- it all stayed on one line, which is not well formatted, or pretty.

Comment: XML is not HTML! In HTML, there is *void elements*, this allows to write either `<tag>` or `<tag />` both valid in the same context. But XML is comparable to XHTML.

Answer (score 54):

The answers on this question are not only wrong, but dangerous. 
CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B will not indent HTML but XML. Consider the following HTML code:

```
<span class="myClass"></span>
```

The function 'Notepad++ -> Plugins -> XmlTools -> Pretty print (Xml only with line breaks)' (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B) will transform this to:

```
<span class="myClass"/>
```

which will not be displayed correctly anymore by your browser! I strongly advice against using this function to indent HTML.

Instead use the plugin **Tidy2**. This will indent the HTML correctly without bad side-effects (but it will also create `<html>, <head>, <body>, ...` elements around your code, if these are not there).

Comment: So much this. As an amateur html/js learner I just had a terrible half an hour trying to understand why my page just didn't render at all - and the reason was that `<script src="somewhere"></script>` collapsed into `<script src="somewhere"/>`

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't look like it works with the 64-bit version of Notepad++, which is a deal killer for me.

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai Most of plugins (including Plugin Manager) are not yet available in x64 - if you rely on Notepad++ plugins, it's advisable to install the 32 bit version of Notepad++ instead to be able to use plugins. If that is not an option, then you have to use a different editor - i.e. [Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/how-do-i-reformat-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Yah you're right. Don't know why I thought it was a deal killer... it's not like it improves that much with 64 bit.

Comment: For reference "Plugin Manager" (which is different from the built-in Plugin Admin) is now available as 64 bits version, but Tidy2 is still not available as 64 bits.

Answer (score 25):

Step 1: Open plugin manager in notepad++

Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager.

Step 2:install XML Tool plugin

Search "XML TOOLS" from the "Available" option then click in install.

***Now you can use shortcut key CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B to indent the code.***

Comment: This answer is the same as the earlier one above and is for XML not HTML!

Answer (score 19):

I have a solution for you.

Just you need to install a plugin named `Indent By Fold`.

> You can install this by going through `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager`. OR
>   `Plugins -> Plugins Admin -> chekmark Indent By Fold from list` than install

Then just select the list item and all you need is to type the first word then you got it.

you can use this plugin from a plugin in the menu bar.

Comment: For HTML this produces a correct indentation, where XML Tool would produce an unbalanced indentation due to HTML<->XML differences.

Comment: No longer available in the plugin manager as far as I can see.

Comment: Just realized that's probably because I'm using the 64bit version of N++

Comment: This is the correct answer. Works better than `XML Tools`.

Comment: It only works on the code you got "on screen"the rest of the document isn't indented..

Comment: XML Tools indented incorrectly in my case. However, this worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Constantin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199308/how-to-indent-html-tags-in-notepad/48014716#answer-37617122), here's the essence of what I learned while transitioning to Notepad++ as my primary HTML editor.

**Install [Notepad++ 32-bit](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download)**

There's no 64-bit version of Tidy2 and some other popular plugins. The 32-bit version of NPP has few practical downsides, so axe the 64-bit version.

**Install the [Plugin Manager](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases)**

Plugin Manager isn't strictly necessary for plugin usage. It does make things much easier, though.

Plugin Manager was [eliminated](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5-released.html) from the core package apparently because the developer didn't like some included attribution linking.

> You may notice that Plugin Manager plugin has been removed from the
>   official distribution. The reason is Plugin Manager contains the
>   advertising in its dialog. I hate Ads in applications, and I ensure
>   you that there was no, and there will never be Ads in Notepad++.

It's a manual install, but it's not difficult.

1. [Download](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases) the UNI (32-bit) zip package and extract it. Inside you'll see folders called *plugins* and *updater*. Each contains one file.
2. Drag those two files to the respective identically-named folders in your Notepad++ installation directory. Typically that's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++`.
3. Restart Notepad++ and follow any install/update prompts.

Now you'll see a new entry under Plugins for Plugin Manager.

**Install [Tidy2](https://github.com/bruderstein/NppTidy2) (or your preferred alternative)**

In Plugin Manager, check the box for Tidy2. Click Install. Restart when prompted.

To use Tidy2, select one of the preconfigured profiles in its Plugins submenu item, or create your own.

Answer (score 1):

On Notepadd++ v7.5.9 (32-bits), "Indent by fold" plugin is working fine with html content.

1. Search and install in plugin manager
2. Use "Plugins" > "Indent by fold" > "Reindent file"

https://www.fesevur.com/indentbyfold/

Answer (score -1):

In Notepad++ v7.8.9 you can use the `Tab` key to increase the indention level, and use `Shift + Tab` to decrease the indentation level.