# Unable to pretty print HTML using XML Tools for NotePad++

Tags: html, notepad++, pretty-print

When trying to pretty-print the formatting of my HTML code in Notepad++ using a tip found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/auto-format-indent-for-xml-html-in-notepad)! I get the "errors detected in content" message.

Upon "check xml syntax now" with xml-tools I get "XML parsing error at line 15. Premature end of data tag html in line 2."

I've shrunk down my HTML to the bare minimum in an attempt to locate the error. Am I missing something obvious here?

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>title</title>
        <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

running this code through a online HTML Validator receives 
these Error / warnings:

```
<meta> Lacks "content" Attribute (At line 4, column 9)
<link> Lacks "type" Attribute (At line 9, column 9)
```

you can fix them and try again