# Contemporary Solution for Formatting HTML in Notepad++

Tags: html, formatting, notepad++

It seems this should be a basic and comomon requirement, but after an hour of searching instead of getting on with the task I want to use it for, I can't find an effective solution for formatting HTML in Notepad++.

I've visited [Formatting code in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635460/formatting-code-within-notepad) and [How To Auto-Format / Indent XML/HTML in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad) but

- XML tools plugin - no good because it doesn't even align opening and closing head tags.
- TextFX HTML Tidy - no good. Missing dll, link from menu to dll broken and all SO solutions involve putting the dll once found into plugins/config directory which my install doesn't have (Maybe I could create it, but I want an easier solution now)
- Tidy2 - won't install

I'm using Windows 10 on a 64-bit machine. I love Notepad++ but this sucks. Please put me out of my misery.

Comment: This question belongs on superuser, not stackoverflow or ask here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/

Comment: OK, Tidy2 now installs. I've no idea what made it work. I installed and ununstalled several different plugins and then tried to install tidy2 and it worked.

Comment: However... Tidy2 breaks my HTML. Can't give details because it's a long webpage I downloaded - it just works before applying and not after..

Comment: Does the page validate?

Comment: What do you mean by `... Tidy2 breaks my HTML`?