# How i do proper code formatting in Notepad++ in any programming language

Tags: notepad++

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
    Java Script file
  </title>
  <script>
    alert("Hacked file!")
    document.write("Hello world!");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Notepad++ could not format this code how i apply source formatting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Auto-Format / Indent XML/HTML in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

Select all html and...

> TextFX -> HTML Tidy -> Tidy: Reindent XML

You may need to install the TextFX plugin if you do not have it already. https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/ or more easily:

> Plugins > Plugin manager > TextFX > Install

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the XML tool from the Plugins --> Plugin Manager --> show Plugin Manager and then check the XML tools, install it and then Ctl+Alt+Shift+B OR the option for XML Tool above shows up.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad)

Answer (score -2):

go for visual studio.it will let you format it. in fact it will allow you to write,compile,edit any code of almost any programming language.