# How to display SVG Markup in Browser - Large File Size (40MB)

Tags: html, svg

[image: Screenshot of browser console log showing SVG markup]

Above is SVG markup (vector graphics) printed in console. I want to display this graphics. However, when I try to copy and paste it in a new HTML viewer, the **graphics does not show perfectly**.

I have **tried online editors (HTML formatters) but they crash every time** because the **file is too big (35.5MB)**.

Can anyone suggest me what is missing in the markup so it can be displayed in a browser or other viewers?

Comment: It looks like a SVG instead of HTML. Are you sure it's a HTML file?

Comment: @Raptor, Yes its an SVG file , HTML file can also run it right?

Comment: Indeed, looks like SVG markup. Try to put the code inside an <SVG> tag like shown on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Auto-Format / Indent XML/HTML in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117949/how-to-auto-format-indent-xml-html-in-notepad)

Comment: I'm afraid some browsers/applications might also crash trying to render such a huge file. If you're dynamically generating this svg you should consider to reduce the output first: number of elements, floating point accuracy, remove unnecessary attributes (e.g fill-rule) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you are on Windows use Notepad++ it can handle very large files.
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

What you have is SVG markup but in order to display it you need to put it inside an `<SVG>` element, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg

Make a new empty file and enter the following code and paste the code from the console to the indicated place:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
PASTE THE CODE HERE
</svg>
```

Save the file as `pic.svg` and open it in your browser (for example Chrome and MS Edge can display SVG files directly).

You will have to adapt the `viewbox` coordinates to the actual size of the image. The code above assumes that the picture coords go from (0,0) to (1000,1000) - but your picture might be smaller or larger.

Comment: Alternatively, SVG can be opened in design software like Adobe Illustrator for editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that it might be simpler and smaller to put all of them in one file using stuff like style and script tags, but it's ok if i'm wrong tho :)