# TextFX menu is missing in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

There is no TextFX menu in the menu bar in my Notepad++ installation.

How do I add it?

There is nothing in `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Available tab`

---

I reinstalled as Dave recommended in his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699834/362951), but nothing changed.

Comment: Curious why would this question be migrated *from* superuser.com?  Don't get me wrong I'd rather my questions be here too because they're more likely to get answered (and answered by a programmer which I generally prefer) but I'm just surprised.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It should usually work using the method [Dave described in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699834/362951). (I can confirm seeing "TextFX Characters" in the *Available* tab in Plugin Manager.)

If it does not, you can try downloading the zip file [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/) and put its contents (it's one file called `NppTextFX.dll`) inside the `plugins` folder where Notepad++ is installed. I suggest doing this while Notepad++ itself is not running.

Comment: I downloaded it from [here](http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/npptextfx_dll.html) and put it to the `plugins` directory. No need to extract. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I forgot to add the link where you can get the TextFX plugin. Glad you were able to find a workaround, though.

Comment: I am afraid this one is for 32 bits platform, it will not work with Notepad++ 64 bits executable

Comment: is this plugin is available for 64-bit version ?

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this answer and I can't remove the vote. This is a note to myself that this is in fact the answer that solved my problem.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir , not officially. The source is available on github and there are alpha builds of 64-bit. It's in this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672000/5326885

Comment: This doesn't work for current versions, try the answer from @Voicu below

Answer (score 47):

**For 32 bit Notepad++  only**

Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Available tab -> TextFX Characters -> Install.

It was removed from the default installation as it caused issues with certain configurations, and there's no maintainer.

Comment: Plugin Manager says: No new plugins available.

Comment: Neither in `Updates`. `Installed` contains `Converter`, `NppExport`, `NppFTP`, `Plugin Manager` and `Spell-Checker`.

Comment: @AWE For me it was a firewall issue and no amount of re-installs fixed the problem. I amended the firewall rules for Notepad++ and the 'Plugin Manager' then displayed the full list of downloadable plugins under the 'Available' tab. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is "TextFX Characters" the same thing as "TextFX"? I find this confusing. If I'm not mistaken it was simply titled "TextFX" when you went to the Plugin Manager and then Available tab (or Installed or Updated tab in case you already have it installed). Have they renamed it? Anyway! Installing *the* "TextFX Characters" brought back the TextFX menu for me. I'm using version 6.5.4 freshly released and installed on a new computer.

Comment: @sammyg Yes, they *are* the same. I used the Updates Manager and installed "TextFX Characters" plugin. After updating, I compared it to the zipped DLL downloaded from SF, and the DLL's match in size (224 KB) and name "NppTextFX.dll"

Comment: I don't see this in the list of plugins

Comment: Updated to v8.5.3 (32 bit version), and lost TextFX plugin, to get it back it had the same name as suggested for the 64-bit version - NppTextFX

Answer (score 22):

For Notepad++ **64-bit**:

There is an unreleased 64-bit version of this plugin. You can download the DLL from [here](https://github.com/HQJaTu/NPPTextFX/blob/VS2017-x64/bin/x64/NppTextFX.dll), drop it under *Notepad++/plugins/NppTextFX* directory and restart Notepad++. You will need to create the *NppTextFX* directory first though.

As per [this](https://github.com/HQJaTu/NPPTextFX/issues/1) GitHub issue, there might be some bugs lurking around. If you run into any, feel free to raise a GitHub ticket for each, as the author ([HQJaTu](https://github.com/HQJaTu)) is recommending. As per the author, the code behind this binary is found on [this](https://github.com/HQJaTu/NPPTextFX/tree/VS2017-x64) branch.

[image]

Tested on Notepad++ v7.5.8 (64-bit, Build time: Jul 23 2018)

Comment: Virus detected in that download link.

Comment: Yep.  That's a trojan.

Comment: @sirdodger: So is it a virus or a trojan? Can you include the definition name and the application that raised the warning? This could be a false positive. The paranoid can always build from the sources found on [this](https://github.com/HQJaTu/NPPTextFX/tree/VS2017-x64) branch after reviewing the code.

Comment: [Here](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/5954a0741d4c38913af3ea7e4e2f97695c174b9dba437db5b4ecb3d1a1b9c092/detection) is an online malware analysis of that .dll after being scanned with 66 different tools. No malware was found.

Comment: Sorry, a trojan.  The definition triggered was Trojan:Win32/Spursint.F!cl

Comment: I accidentally upvoted this answer and I can't remove the vote. This is a note to myself that the standard Notepad++ download is 32 bit.

Comment: Was able to get it working on my 7.6.2 installation. Did run into a blocking issue with it waiting on lync.exe for some reason (found through Resource Monitor). Had to close Skype for Business, then Notepad++ continued launching. Skype could launch again afterwords. Goofy, but something to keep on eye on

Comment: Not wanting to take the risk after the comments above, I recompiled the x64 bit version from source myself, available [here](http://phdesign.com.au/programming/notepadpp-textfx-64bit/)

Comment: The binary in my GitHub repository, is definitely not a trojan. False positive, but no malware.

Comment: 7.7.1 the x64 no longer works when dropped in the plugin folder.

Comment: It must be a subfolder named for the plugin.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58657419/871821

Comment: @Voicu: Please include the hint with the subfolder named "NppTextFX" in your reply

Comment: NppTextFX64/NppTextFX64.dll worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

A lot of the old TextFX operations like removing empty lines and sorting are available under:

> Menu *Edit → Line Operations*

Comment: This answer is definitely underrated, the cases operations I also found there :)

Comment: Thanks! This did what I needed; sorting, duplicates removal.

Comment: The Edit menu has no Line Operations entry in my Notepad++ on Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: That's odd - I'm on windows 10 too and have updated to the latest NPP and the option's still there between Convert Case To and Comment/Uncomment...

Answer (score 5):

Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Setting -> Check mark On Force HTTP instead of HTTPS for downloading Plugin List & Use development plugin list (may contain untested, unvalidated or un-installable plugins). -> OK.

Comment: There is no such `Plugins -> Plugin Manager`.