# Notepad++ Search Multiple and Replace Respectively

Tags: string, notepad++

Doing some String manipulation and I want to ask if the below is possible in Notepad++:

I have a string with Years:

```
10-Jan-13
22-Feb-14
10-Jan-13
10-Mar-13
```

I want

```
10-JAN-13
22-FEB-14
10-JAN-13
10-MAR-13
```

(There's more data on each line there but I am just showing a simplified example).

I know I can OR search with | character so find, JAN|FEB|MAR... but how do I replace according to what's found.

(Just trying to save some time)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a plugin or built-in, but you can use the *TextFX Characters* plugin, to select the text, and then in the textfx characters dropdown, click UPPER CASE.

### Update

Looks like it is a plugin:

[TextFX menu is missing in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699833/textfx-menu-is-missing-in-notepad)

### Multiple Files

I found this site which gives a way to convert text to uppercase with regular expressions: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions

So, what you can do is bring up the find in files dialog (CTRL+SHIFT+F), change search mode to Regular Expression, and then use something like this:

Find: `(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2})`
Replace with: `\U\1`

Directory: Whichever directory your files are in (and only the files you want changed).

`\U` is an uppercase flag, and the brackets in the Find regex correspond with the `\1` backreference, which will basically replace it with itself (but uppercase).

Comment: Ok that looks good - however i have multiple files and each line has multiple pieces of info so I dont want to select.

Comment: Added a Find in Files solution for you @SaeUs

Comment: Fantastic that works! However I need to read on regex to understand what the \d and \w mean. Thanks again

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  \d is digit, {2} finds exactly two digits, which would find the day and years in your example, and \w is word character which would match the months between the hyphens exactly {3}  of them.