# Visual Studio editor invert character case shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, text-editor

I wanted to know if there is any shortcut to switch letter case

example:

`doItYourself` to became `DOiTyOURSELF`

or

`DOiTyOURSELF` to became `doItYourself`

(I am using VS2010 but I wanted to know generally)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. There's only functionality for [upper and lower case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165341%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Notepad++ has this function in menu `TextFX > TextFX Characters > iNVERT cASE`. Also, check out the [relevant question](https://superuser.com/questions/568424/how-to-easily-invert-upper-lower-case-in-common-text-editors) from Super User for other alternatives.

If this functionality is so much required in Visual Studio itself, you can make a Visual Studio [add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (better than VS macros).

Comment: Thank you.  I use notepad++ to, but I can't find TextFX menu. Is it on top level?

Comment: In certain versions it was [hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12699833/395718) due to lack of maintenance. Try installing the latest version. Also try to install it through `Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager`, and in `Available` tab check the box for `TextFX Characters`.

Comment: @Endri, glad I could help. Make sure you support the workings of Stack Overflow by rewarding all useful answers, accepting the answer that is correct for your case.

Comment: Ok, but instead I asked for Visual Studio.